# How to remove this gear from this pump and motor?

Tags: gears

Actual story is both driven & driver gear teeths are warped up.
I am trying to remove this **gear coupling** from the motor side using ***gear pulling device*** by applying load, but it still not coming: [image]

and also driven gear got stuck in the gear pump. but how to remove it?

this image of driven gear:[image]

Comment: Heat and penetrating oil both good, as others say. ALSO cold from eg CO2 extinguisher or other expanding gas or liquid. LPG may work for cooling but poses an explosion hazard

Comment: Do you need the parts intact?

Answer (score 3):

Heat is going to be your friend. Localize it to the gear so as to keep as much direct heat away from the shaft and other parts. If you have your puller on with tension applied, you'll see when the part starts to separate, then you can apply more pressure at that point to the puller.

As far as the driven gear, I cannot see enough of how it's attached to anything to give you proper advice.

Answer (score 2):

I've had success with using penetrating oil and lightly hitting the shaft with a hammer a few times to help it get between the shaft and the gear.

If that doesn't work, get a torch (or an induction heater if you have one) and heat the gear sleeve.

Answer (score 1):

Since both gears are trash, use a cut off wheel, and cut parallel to the key. Once through it should pop right off with out much effort.